# Redirect subdomain.domain.com to www.subdomain.domain.com

Tags: nginx, redirection, virtualhost

We have currently a wildcard vhost accepting all domain request.

I want to redirect 
`subdomain.domain.com` to `www.subdomain.domain.com` so my wildcard  will answer

One exception, I dont want to redirect `www.domain.com` to `www.www.domain.com`

How to achieve that ? I've put together (outside the wildcard block) but it's not dealing with the exception and not sure about the variable thing

```
if ($http_host ~ (.*).domain.com) {
    set $test P;
}

if ($http_host != www.domain.com) {
    set $test  "${test}C";
}

if ($http_host != www.*.domain.com) {
    set $test  "${test}D";
}

if ($test = PCD) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ www.%1.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this rule using if, using if is not recommended if ($http_host = subdomain.domain.com) { rewrite ^(.*)$ www.subdomain.domain.com$1 permanent;  }

Comment: I know the domain but not the subdomain (there'll be 300 subdomains), how to add dynamic part to it ?

Comment: Try this for Dynamic subdomains if ($http_host ~ (.*).domain.com) { rewrite ^(.*)$ www.%1.domain.com$1 permanent;    I have not tried this, but it should work

Comment: Question edited. I end up with 414 URI too long with url like : `http://www.subdomain.domain.com/www.domain.com/www.domain.com/.......`

Comment: Try this if ($http_host ~ ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).domain.com$) { rewrite ^(.*)$ www.%1.domain.com$1 permanent;

Comment: Still not working, www.domain.com redirects on a loop. We'll handle this manually on the DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    # this is default server.
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.*;

    # here www.*.example.com
    ..
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 http://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```